# Can Harry Potter swim?

Tags: harry-potter

In *The Goblet of Fire*, when Harry, upon taking Cedric's hint, goes to the prefects' bathroom, he spends a few minutes admiring the place and then does a few laps in the tub (which was apparently as large as a swimming pool). Later on, when he figures out what he needs to rescue, he gets disheartened, because apparently the Dursleys never took him to swimming lessons.

So, which is true? Can he or can he not swim?

Comment: Like most things in life, "knowing how to swim" is not a black and white thing. You don't go straight from "has never been in a body of water larger than a puddle" to "Michael Phelps", with nothing in between.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the tub, no matter how long and wide it is, were so deep that he couldn't stand in it with his head above the water.

Comment: I’m also guessing that the Dursleys would go to the pool with Dudley *amd* Harry, get Dudley lessons, and let Harry try to drown.

Comment: I've known how to swim since I was 2 and have no problem going into any kind of water. What I _don't_ know how to do (or at least, I haven't done it much and am not good at it at all) is dive down deep and stay there. The human body is very bouyant. Swimming deep is a skill that takes practice to develop.

Answer (score 91):

He can't swim... *very well*.

> But he suddenly realised what he was saying, and he felt the
> excitement drain out of him as though someone had just pulled a plug
> in his stomach. **He wasn’t a very good swimmer;** he’d never had much
> practice. Dudley had had lessons in their youth, but Aunt Petunia and
> Uncle Vernon, no doubt hoping that Harry would drown one day, hadn’t
> bothered to give him any. **A couple of lengths of this bath was all
> very well, but that lake was very large, and very deep** … and merpeople
> would surely live right at the bottom …
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

Having gone to a British primary school, it's likely he would have had a few lessons as part of his normal class activities, but only enough to prevent casual drowning.

---

In later books he seems to have no trouble swimming in open water.

> And with the sudden agility of a much younger man, Dumbledore slid
> from the boulder, landed in the sea and began to swim, with a perfect
> breaststroke, towards the dark slit in the rock face, his lit wand
> held in his teeth. Harry pulled off his Cloak, stuffed it into his
> pocket and followed.
>
> The water was icy; Harry’s waterlogged clothes billowed around him and
> weighed him down. Taking deep breaths that filled his nostrils with
> the tang of salt and seaweed, he struck out for the shimmering,
> shrinking light now moving deeper into the cliff.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

Comment: His time in primary school was entirely before they were required to provide swimming lessons (that was 1994), but I agree that he likely did have lessons, given that he can swim to some degree.

Comment: Perhaps it's a British-ism, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'casual' with regard to drowning.

Comment: Interesting that in Britain primary school children learn swimming... in the US (at least most of it), most kids don't get any access to a pool as part of normal class activities... Only if you go to a fancy school, join swim team, or most common learn to swim outside of school.

Comment: Most elementary schools in the US don't have pools, but some ordinary public high schools do.  We occasionally swam as part of gym class.

Comment: @user3067860: It's common in France to learn to swim at some point too. Schools will typically reserve a time at the local swimming pool, in the morning during working hours when the pools are mostly empty.

Comment: @TylerH - 'casual' drowning would be drowning that's easily avoided by even a tiny amount of exposure to swimming, such as in a placid lake or a swimming pool without a lifeguard.  It means "You can swim well enough that you aren't at risk of drowning in otherwise calm water."

Comment: @TylerH in the UK we still have formal drownings where young women are taken to lakes, ponds and streams to be formally tested. No amount of lessons can save you from that unless you weigh the same as a duck. (/s)

Comment: @MD-Tech Or have a natural gift for knots and plenty of practise at holding your breath underwater. (Miss Tick from Terry Pratchett's "Tiffany Aching" strand of Diskworld books.)

Comment: @Graham and subtly influence your would-be drowners with carefully written books on how to drown witches.

Comment: Definitely no one wants to be a filthy casual at drowning. Hardcore competitive drowning is where it's at.

Comment: @JeannePindar Most British schools don't have a swimming pool, be they primary or secondary. I expect the fancy fee-paying ones do, but I'd be surprised to encounter a state school that has one. It's more common to do what Matthieu says French schools tend to do - commandeer the local public pool for an hour or so.

Comment: @Pharap  - Lots of schools used to have a dedicated pool but it's quite an expense for only occasional use.

Comment: @Valorum How far back is 'used to'?

Comment: @Pharap - In the 1960s there were over 20,000 dedicated school swimming pools in primary and secondary schools. That number is now under 600